# Continuity and strict convexity on (a,b) implies strict convexity on [a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've been working on convexity/concavity. The definition I am using is that a function $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, iff

$f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)\leq (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)$ for all $ x,y\in I, x<y$, $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

I stumbled upon the result that $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R},x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is strictly concave. This is often "proven" by the second derivative test, however $f$ does not have a derivative at $x=0$. One way to save the proof is by invoking a statement that sounds true to me: If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly convex on the interior $(a,b)$ and continuous on $x=a$ and $x=b$, then it is strictly convex on $[a,b]$. I have proven a similar result for convex but not strictly convex functions, but the proof does not translate to the strictly convex case. Also I'm not 100 % sure if the statement is indeed true, it appears not to be true in the multidimensional case, as is discussed in this thread:

[Continuity + strict convexity on interior implies strict convexity everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846688/continuity-strict-convexity-on-interior-implies-strict-convexity-everywhere?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have thought about a proof but cannot come up with one. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is convex, and there is $\lambda_0 \in (0,1)$ with $f((1-\lambda_0)x + \lambda_0 y) = (1-\lambda_0)f(x) + \lambda_0f(y)$, then $f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) = (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$ holds for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$. ($x$ and $y$ arbitrary but fixed)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thanks for your hint. I figured a proof, hope it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this proof:

Since $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex (as proven before),

$f(\xi)\leq f(x) + \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}(\xi -x)\quad \forall a<x<\xi<b.$

Suppose that $f$ is not strictly convex, i. e. there are $a<x_0<\xi_0<b$ such that

$f(\xi_0)= f(x_0)+ \frac{f(b)-f(x_0)}{b-x_0}(\xi_0 -x_0)$.

Then (using the hint by Daniel Fischer)

$f(\xi)= f(x_0)+ \frac{f(b)-f(x_0)}{b-x_0}(\xi -x_0) \quad \forall x_0<\xi<b$. (I)

Since $f$ is strictly convex by assumption,

$f(\xi)= f(x_0)+ \frac{f(\xi_0)-f(x_0)}{\xi_0-x_0}(\xi -x_0) \quad \forall x_0<\xi<\xi_0$. (II)

Also since $f$ is convex,

$\frac{f(\xi_0)-f(x_0)}{\xi_0-x_0}\leq \frac{f(b)-f(x_0)}{b-x_0}$. (III)

By (I), (II) and (III), for a $x_0<\xi_1<\xi_0$ we have

$f(\xi_1)<f(x_0)+ \frac{f(\xi_0)-f(x_0)}{\xi_0-x_0}(\xi_1 -x_0)\leq f(x_0)+ \frac{f(b)-f(x_0)}{b-x_0}(\xi_1 -x_0)=f(\xi_1)$.

Since this is a contradiction, the assumption was wrong and that concludes the proof.

Is this a valid proof?